# Error with the java code pls

Tags: java, error-handling, compiler-errors

I have this code on the internet and i can't run them pls tell me know
 why???

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    keyboard[Scanner] = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print( "Hello. What is your name? " );
    name[String] = keyboard[Scanner].next();

    System.out.print( "Hi, " + name[String] + "! How old are you? " );
    age[int] = keyboard[Scanner].nextInt();

    System.out.println("So you're " + age[int] + ", eh? That's not so old.");
    System.out.print( "How much do you weigh, " + name[String] + "? " );
    weight[double] = keyboard[Scanner].nextDouble();

    System.out.println( weight[double] + "! Better keep that quiet!!" );
    System.out.print("Finally, what's your income, " + name[String] + "? " );
    income[double] = keyboard[Scanner].nextDouble();

    System.out.print( "Hopefully that is " + income[double] + " per hour" );
    System.out.println( " and not per year!" );
    System.out.print( "Well, thanks for answering my rude questions, " );
    System.out.println( name[String] + "." );
}
```

***Help me please!! Thanks!!!***

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Those "type references" aren't even Java. Where did you even get this?

Comment: At the book learn java hard way !!

Comment: Is this a new way of declaring variables in java ? which holy java version are you using ?

Comment: Maybe .. just maybe ... those `[]` are telling you what you need to declare the objects as ... and not just a copy paste of the entire code ...

Comment: Netbean IDE 8.2 bro!! I just see this on the book and try to run them!! I haven't seen it before!!!

Comment: Methinks you've not shown us all the code.

Comment: From the "book" (https://learnjavathehardway.org/book/ex08.html) : I have written some code to show what Java might be like if you had to add the type of a variable every time you used it. **Don’t bother typing it up; it won’t compile since Java (thankfully) doesn’t work like that.**

Comment: Yes i know !! I just see it on the book and try to run it!!

Comment: But the book tells you that you shouldn't try to run it as it isn't valid java code! It already tells you its wrong, so what do you want from us?

Comment: Oh!! That's mine mistake !! Sorry for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the book you mentioned in the comments. . just after this code ... the statement in the book is :
[image]

> Whew! Aren't you glad you don't ahve to do that every time you use a variable ??

what you need is below :

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print( "Hello. What is your name? " );
    String name = keyboard.next();

    System.out.print( "Hi, " + name+ "! How old are you? " );
    int age = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("So you're " + age + ", eh? That's not so old.");
    System.out.print( "How much do you weigh, " + name + "? " );
    double  weight = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println( weight + "! Better keep that quiet!!" );
    System.out.print("Finally, what's your income, " + name + "? " );
    double income = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.print( "Hopefully that is " + income + " per hour" );
    System.out.println( " and not per year!" );
    System.out.print( "Well, thanks for answering my rude questions, " );
    System.out.println( name + "." );
}
```